# How to use foldr correctly in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, fold

I'm trying to write a function which behave like this:

```
correctCards :: [Card] -> [Card] -> Int
```

It takes two lists of type Card and check for how many cards are the same. Here is my code:

```
correctCards answer guess = foldr step acc guess
        where 
            acc = 0
            step acc guess
                | elem (head guess) answer  = acc + 1
                | otherwise                 = acc
```

But the types are not match. Can someone tell me where I went wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Given the two lists `[A, K, Q]` and `[A, Q, J]` do you expect to return `1` (since only the first positions match) or `2` (since there is a `A` and a `Q` in each list)?

Comment: `step 0 guess` should be `step acc guess` really.

Comment: Returns 2. Order is immaterial.

Comment: I changed "0" to "acc" but it still doesn't work. Do I misuse foldr? Since I'm new in Haskell, and I'm trying to right something like do what a loop does in Java.

Comment: I would write it as ``correctCards = (length .: intersect) `on` nub``.

Comment: @user3928256 even in Java with a loop this would not do what you replied to Chris - in Java you would use something like a Hashset and count the intersection too (as Aadit did

Comment: @AaditMShah +1 - but maybe `(.:)` is a bit hard to understand for newbies ;)

Comment: Indeed I have no idea what ".:" means...

Comment: Interesing, I cannot find `(.:)` on hoogle.

Comment: @user3928256 I think it's `let (.:) = (.) . (.)` here

Comment: @Paul you will find it on hayoo - it's not really a standard operator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at `foldr`'s type:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

Now, that means that the function you supply must be of type `a -> b -> b`. Given the following code:

```
foldr step 0 cards
-- cards :: [Card]
-- 0     :: Integer
-- step  :: ???
```

what should the type of `step` be? Given by our arguments, `a` should be `Card` and `b` should be `Integer`:

```
-- concrete type of `foldr` in this case
foldr :: (Card -> Integer -> Integer) -> Integer -> [Card] -> Integer
```

Therefore, `step` should have the type `(Card -> Integer -> Integer)`. Compare this to *your* step function:

```
step acc guess
    | elem (head guess) answer  = acc + 1
    | otherwise                 = acc
```

In this case `step` is `Integer -> [Card] -> Integer`. And that's not the correct type. Instead, you want

```
step guess acc
     | elem guess answer = acc + 1
     | otherwise         = acc
```

Note that `step` only takes a *single*, not a whole list.