# How to use (.) in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pointfree, function-composition, combinators, dot-operator

I'm trying to write something like this in Haskell:

```
length . nub . intersect
```

but it doesn't work.

```
*Main Data.List> :t intersect
intersect :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
*Main Data.List> :t nub
nub :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
*Main Data.List> :t length
length :: [a] -> Int
```

Based on the type, my understanding is that `intersect` returns a type of `[a]` and donates to `nub` , which takes exactly a type of `[a]` , then also returns a type of `[a]` to `length` , then finally the return should be an `Int`. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Actually, `intersect` returns a type of `[a] -> [a]`. `((length . nub) .) . intersect` will do what you want, but my understanding here is too weak to answer.

Comment: see also: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree#Dot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that `intersect` *takes 2 arguments* (in a sense)

you can provide one of the arguments explicitly:

```
> let f a = length . nub . intersect a
> :t f
f :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Int
```

or you can use a fun little operator like `(.:) = (.) . (.)`:

```
> let (.:) = (.) . (.)
> :t length .: (nub .: intersect)
length .: (nub .: intersect) :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Int
```

here is a version where you don't need the parens:

import Data.List

```
infixr 9 .:

(.:) :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
(.:) = (.).(.)

f :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Int
f = length .: nub .: intersect
```

Comment: Thanks! I now finally understand what ".:" means now!

Answer (score 4):

I guess this is based on the comments in your previous question, where [@CarstenKönig mentions `(.) . (.)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25722198/how-to-use-foldr-correctly-in-haskell#comment40213004_25722198).

First of all, `length . nub . intersect` cannot work. Your types are:

```
(.)       ::         (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
length    ::         [a] -> Int
nub       :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
intersect :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a] ~ [a] -> ([a] -> [a])
```

As you can see, `intersect` has the wrong type, in the context of `(.)`, the type parameter `b` would be replaced by `([a] -> [a])`, which isn't the type of `nub`'s first argument.

Comment: Oh right! Thanks! It is based on the former question ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'd say this: write your code the "dumb" way at first, and then refactor it to use `(.)`.  After some practice the composition operator will then become like second nature.

So you'd first write:

```
yourFunction xs ys = length (nub (intersect xs ys))
```

What `(.)` lets you do is get rid (syntactically) of the last argument of the innermost function, all all the parens.  In this case that argument is `ys`:

```
yourFunction xs = length . nub . intersect xs
```